# Want to get data in array from API in React Js

Tags: reactjs

I want to get data in array from the API but not able to find the exact solution and i am new to React.js
I am trying to get the data in temp array from the API but not able to figure it out how to use new state as i am already using one setState in componentDidMount method.

```
 Code till componentDidMount method:

   class Apiapp extends Component{
      constructor(){
      super()
      this.state = {
        loading:true,
        characters:{}
     }
    }
     componentDidMount(){
         // This means we can use the setState method as many times are we can depending on what 
        type of methods are we using
        // this.setState({
        //   loading:true
        // })
        fetch("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/5")
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
             let tmpArray = []
             for (var i = 0; i < data.game_indices.length; i++) {
                tmpArray.push(data.game_indices[i])
             }
              console.log(data)
              this.setState({
              loading:false,
              characters:data
            })
            this.setState({
              loading:false,
              arrCharacters:tmpArray
            })
          })
      }

     Code of render method:

     render() {
      let text = this.state.loading ? <h2>Loading...</h2> : <div><h2> 
                {this.state.characters.name} 

                </h2>,<h2>{this.state.arrCharacters.name}</h2></div>

               // <h2>{this.state.characters.game_indices[0].version.name}</h2>

                return(<div>{text}</div>)
  }
}
```

I am trying to get all the names that is in "game_indices".

API link: https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/ditto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't overcomplicate things

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class ApiApp extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loading: true,
      characters: {},
    };
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    const data = await fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/5').then((response) => response.json());

    this.setState({ characters: data.game_indices, loading: false });
  }

  render() {
    return <div>{this.state.loading ? <h2>Loading...</h2> : this.state.characters.map((i) => i.version.name)}</div>;
  }
}
```

I'm not too sure what data you are trying to display - its not that clear from the question

Comment: My straight forward question is that i want to display list of names that are in this link " https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/ditto" names are blue,gold, ruby and so on. please see the API i want to diplay game_indices":[{"game_index":76,"version":{"name":"red" ==> these names i want ot get in list.

Comment: @nitinbakaya answer updated. You need to use i.version.name

Comment: Your code is just showing Loading.... no data. I think that you missed something.

Comment: @nitinbakaya you are correct - I forgot to set loading to false.. I have updated the answer

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing the easy and much more concise solution than the first one posted by other Guy.

Answer (score 1):

There are cleaner ways to achieve the same result. However, I'd rather explain what it is wrong with your code:

Check the comments below in your code

```
import { Component } from 'react'

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      loading: true,
      characters: {},
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      loading: true,
    })
    fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/5')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        let tmpArray = []
        for (var i = 0; i < data.game_indices.length; i++) {
          tmpArray.push(data.game_indices[i])
        }
        this.setState({
          loading: false,
          characters: data,
        })
        this.setState({
          loading: false,
          arrCharacters: tmpArray,
        })
      })
  }

  //  Code of render method:

  render() {
    let text = this.state.loading ? (
      <h2>Loading...</h2>
    ) : (
      <div>
        <h2>{this.state.characters.name}</h2>,
        {/* 1 - When the page first loads "arrCharacters" is undefined. 
          Therefore you need to add a condition to make sure it is not undefined.
          2- You need to loop through all elements to display the name for each of them. 
          For that, you can use the js array method map.
          3- When you display a list, you must use a unique key as  attribute. 
          4 - After you need to check where the data you want to display lives. 
          In your case, it is inside an obj version. So you access it with "." or "[]"
*/}
        {this.state.arrCharacters &&
          this.state.arrCharacters.map((char) => (
            <h2 key={char.version.name}>{char.version.name}</h2>
          ))}
      </div>
    )

    return <div>{text}</div>
  }
}

export default App
```